# How could we use a neuron instead of 100 neurons in 0.01 standard Weight initialization

Tags: deep-learning, weight-initialization

Many books explain that we don't need to use 100 neurons and just can use a neuron if all result values(sigmoid(Wx)) are same at each of hidden layers.

[image]

[image]

but, I don't know that we can just use a neuron.
Thanks !

Comment: "Many books explain" Can you please cite a book. I do not get what you mean.

Comment: You can refer to weight initialization part in "deep learning from scratch" book